# Syntax Error when executing SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.encrypt 
    @columnname NVARCHAR(100), 
    @TblName NVARCHAR(200) 
WITH ENCRYPTION 
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    DECLARE @encryptcolumn NVARCHAR(200); 
    DECLARE @AlterQuery NVARCHAR(200);
    DECLARE @TblName NVARCHAR(200); 

    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY Password_Key DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE PasswordCertificate;
    SET @encryptcolumn = (@columnname + 'encrypt');

    IF @encryptcolumn IS NOT NULL
        SET @AlterQuery = 'ALTER TABLE ['+@TblName+'] add  ['+@encryptcolumn+'] varbinary(max)null);' 

        EXEC sp_executesql @AlterQuery; 

        UPDATE @TblName 
        SET @encryptcolumn = ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('datamartSymKey'), CONVERT(varbinary, @columnname)) 
    END 
GO
```

When I try to execute this, it's throwing this error:

> The variable name '@TblName' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

Comment: `@TblName` is already a parameter but you try to (re)declare it in the procedure body,

Comment: after removing declare. its not working throwing this error..Must declare the table variable "@TblName"

Comment: If you want to do an update on a dynamic table name, I'm fairly sure you need to use use sp_executesql to execute it as you did with `@AlterQuery` just the line before, not just try to pass the table name as a variable. The syntax you're using requires `@TblName` to be a table variable.

Comment: R Pelzers code below was updated to do just that (although he uses `EXEC` instead of `sp_executesql`) Can't test it, but should do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got this error because you already passed `@tblName` in the procedure. You can solve this by removing the declare and passing the value through the procedure call.

Beside this you have to use `EXEC` to run the update query, because your table name could change.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.encrypt @columnname nvarchar(100), @TblName nvarchar(200) WITH ENCRYPTION AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    DECLARE @encryptcolumn nvarchar(200); 
    DECLARE @AlterQuery nvarchar(200);

    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY Password_Key DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE PasswordCertificate;
    set @encryptcolumn=(@columnname + 'encrypt');
    if @encryptcolumn is not null 
        SET @AlterQuery='ALTER TABLE ['+@TblName+'] add  ['+@encryptcolumn+'] varbinary(max)null);' 
        exec sp_executesql @AlterQuery; 

        DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
        SET @sqlCommand = 'UPDATE ' +@TblName + ' SET ' + @encryptcolumn + ' = ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID(''datamartSymKey''),CONVERT(varbinary, ' + @columnname + '))'
        EXEC (@sqlCommand)
    END 
GO
```

Comment: @R Pelzer when i remove declare its throwing this error..Must declare the table variable "@TblName".

Comment: I updated the code. Because you want to use a variable table name, you have to use an 'EXEC' to run an update query.